# External task execution finished 'signingReport'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-services

I add app_id Google services to my app But when I want to run my app I can't and android studio gives me this message. I can make apk file but Google game services doesn't work,

I'm beginner on programming.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

`Total time: 0.776 secs
12:50:39 PM: External task execution finished 'signingReport'.`

Thanks

Comment: The message doesn't show any problem. Where do you see it doesn't work? Does the app crash? On real device or emulator? If emulator does it hav an imge with google services?

Comment: ----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: none
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\ayoub\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: 19:75:87:C2:CA:4D:B6:4C:5B:65:81:AE:5A:A0:6D:54
SHA1: 69:86:9A:88:6A:36:71:48:A5:6A:46:21:58:13:DB:C1:75:5A:B5:47
Valid until: Sunday, June 30, 2047
----------
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2.478 secs
10:13:52 PM: External task execution finished 'signingReport'.

Comment: That is not a stack trace. You can find the stack trace in the Monitor tab at the bottom of Android Studio after the crash.

Comment: I think the Problem it s on Google Game Services

Comment: The answer is to make your Google services on final version and go to android studio and Take the llast SH1 Code and put it on Google game service

Answer (score 17):

This is happening because you try to run the signing report instead of app. Select app from "Select Run/Debug Configuration" drop down menu as show in below image. then the app will run on device.

[Select Run/Debug Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rLij.png)